# Simple jQuery Calculation Doesnt Return Value

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to calculate the distance from screen width but in the line which i calculate x it returns null. What can be the problem?

```js
$.fn.saveClicks = function() { 
    $(this).bind('mousedown.clickmap', function(evt) { 
        $.post('/clickmap/clickmap.php', {  
            sw:window.innerWidth,
            w:evt.pageX,
            x:((sw/2)-w), 
            y:evt.pageY,  
            l:escape(document.location.pathname) 
        }); 
    }); 
};
```

Comment: Try to every value get throught `parseInt(value);`

Answer (score 1):

`sw` and `w` are no variables, they are properties of the object you declare as an argument in the `$.post` function call.

```
// Declare variables first
var sw = window.innerWidth,
     w = evt.pageX;

$.post('/clickmap/clickmap.php', {
    // Now you can use them in here
    sw: sw,
    w: w,
    x: ((sw/2)-w), 
    y: evt.pageY,  
    l: escape(document.location.pathname) 
});
```

See it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/98qub1uh/).

An object does not have a scope and its properties are not the same as local variables. For example, you can access a variable within an object declaration:

```
var myVariable = 5;
var myObject = { foo: myVariable };
```

But you cannot access other properties of an object during its construction:

```
var myObject = { myVariable: 5, foo: myVariable };
// THIS DOES NOT WORK!
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not calling `$.post()` function correctly. The second parameter must be an object, which can contain multiple `{property: value}` pairs.

Full description of `$.post()` function here:
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

So you must define your variables first, then call $.post function with these variables passed as values for the object properties.

Check out this code:

```
$.fn.saveClicks = function() { 
    $(this).bind('mousedown.clickmap', function(evt) { 
        var sw = window.innerWidth;
        var w = evt.pageX;
        var y = evt.pageY;
        var l = escape(document.location.pathname);
        $.post('/clickmap/clickmap.php', {  
            sw: sw,
            w: w,
            x:((sw/2)-w), 
            y: y,  
            l: l 
        }); 
    }); 
};
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/rqqe0fL4/3/

Comment: "We are the people who teach others to fish. Code-only answers only feed a person for a day." ([source](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148274))

Comment: Which means why don't you explain what you've done so others seeing this, including the OP, can learn from it and not just copy and paste!